# Prestashop 1.6 and multiple discounts

Tags: prestashop-1.6, discount, accumulate

I'd like to cumulate discounts on my prestshop.

For exemple, I have a quantity discount of 20% starts from 5 pieces bought and another discount of 25% on all products who has to be cumulated with the first one.

Now, 25% is apply with less than 5 pieces and 20% with more than 5 pieces. 
I'd like to apply 45% if the quantity is more than 5 pieces.

So, I have to cumulate a custom discount (not a cart rule) with a quantity discount.

I don't know how to do that. Maybe it's possible to do it from the administration panel?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the official documentation about [Cart Rules](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Cart+Rules).
In `Cart Rules` > `[one of your cart rule]` > `Conditions` there's a `Compatibility with other cart rules` check box.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Florian. But the discount is create from a custom module and is unfortunately not a Cart Rules. How can I make it compatible with a quantity discount?